# Writing and saving scraped documents in several sheets in an Excel file

Tags: python, python-3.x, excel, web-scraping

I've written some code in Python for the purpose of scraping names and URLs from several links found in the left sided bar in a webpage and populate the data in several sheets (also giving each sheet a new name taking a customized portion from URL) in an Excel workbook so that things do not get messy and the data can be located separately. I tried to do the whole thing accurately and found it working great. It would be very nice if I get any better idea other than what I did here.

Here is what I tried with:

```
import requests
from lxml import html
from pyexcel_ods3 import save_data

web_link = "http://www.wiseowl.co.uk/videos/"
main_url = "http://www.wiseowl.co.uk"

def get_links(page):

    response = requests.Session().get(page)
    tree = html.fromstring(response.text)
    data = {}
    titles = tree.xpath("//ul[@class='woMenuList']//li[@class='woMenuItem']/a/@href")
    for title in titles:
        if "author" not in title and "year" not in title:
            get_docs(data, main_url + title)

def get_docs(data, url):

    response = requests.Session().get(url)
    tree = html.fromstring(response.text)
    for item in tree.xpath("//p[@class='woVideoListDefaultSeriesTitle']"):
        title = item.findtext('.//a')
        link = item.xpath('.//a/@href')[0]
        sheetname = url.split("videos/")[1].split("/")[1].split(".")[0] 
        if sheetname in data:  
            data[sheetname].append([title, str(link)])  
        else:  
            data[sheetname] = [[title, str(link)]]
    save_data("documents.ods", data)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    get_links(web_link)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Overall I don't think it's terrible. Suggestions:

- Add a shebang to the top of your script so that it's executable in Posix-like environments: `#!/usr/bin/env python`
- You create a session every time you call `get_docs`. Don't do this unless absolutely necessary; instead, pass the session created in `get_links` to be reused.
- Put this through a PEP8 linter, such as that built into PyCharm, for minor formatting suggestions, such as there being two newlines before every top-level function.
- Your `sheetname` (which should be called `sheet_name` by Python standard) smells like it should be a regex instead of a series of splits.
- Condense your `if ... in ... else` to a `setdefault()`; something like:

`data.setdefault(sheet_name, []).append([title, str(link)])`

Comment: Thanks Reinderien for the review. One thing I would like to know- why should I put a blank list in (sheet_name, []) here. Forgive my ignorance. Thanks once again.

Comment: Because if you're using a key that doesn't yet exist in the dictionary, you can set the value to a blank list so that you can still perform the append in the same way.

Answer (score 1):

This is my first review, so take it with a grain of salt! Just one suggestion.

- I would add some code to clean up the HTML prior to creating the `tree`. lxml has an inbuilt cleaner [link](http://lxml.de/lxmlhtml.html#cleaning-up-html). Another method may be a regex solution. I have found cleaning helps avoid issues with those pesky `<!--` IE8 comments. Or getting `<script>` or `<style>` tags in the result. Also if you decide to use BeautifulSoup one day. The results may be more consistent.